# Eclipse is not showing exception stack trace using WAS 8

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, struts

I'm currently seeing this message log in the Eclipse console tab when the code throws an exception. I can't see what the exception actually is.

I'm using Eclipse Kepler and WebSphere Application Server 8.0

```
[1/11/16 08:44:01:962 CST] 00000025 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logError SRVE0293E: [Error de servlet]-[Unable to show problem report: freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "?" at line 41, column 21.
Was expecting:
    <ID> ...
    ]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: Unable to show problem report: freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered &quot;?&quot; at line 41, column 21.
Was expecting:
    &lt;ID&gt; ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I can't see what the exception actually is.

The actual exception message is:

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered ? at line 41, column 21. 
Was expecting:  
    ID ...
```

It looks like there is a parse error in one of your Freemarker templates.

The rest is Websphere saying that it cannot report the problem in a 5xx error page ... probably because the response had already committed.

If you change the Websphere logging level to debug, you should get more clues that will help you to identify the faulty template.

For more info about logging on WAS:

- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHRKX_8.0.0/trouble/adsyslog.html

You should also check to see if Websphere log events are being logged somewhere else; e.g. log files.  Those logs could have full stacktraces.

If all else fails, you could try searching for any Freemarker template that has a question-mark character at line 41, column 21.

Comment: This answer could be added by editing a question or comment, because it doesn't solve OP's problem.